# Capturar evento click de un botón en Fragment desde Activity

Tags: android-fragment, activity, android-button

Tengo un Activity, y dentro de éste un Fragment con un Button y un EditText para "recoger" texto.

Quiero capturar el evento del Buttón desde el Activity pero no me llega a cargar el Fragment, la APP se cierra.

Código del Activity:

```
public class EstadisticasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Fragment insertarJugadaFragment;
ImageButton ibInsertarJugada;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_estadisticas);

    insertarJugadaFragment = new InsertarJugadaFragment();

    // Cargar el fragment inicial (InsertarJugadaFragment)
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.contenedor_fragmentos_estadisticas, insertarJugadaFragment)
            .commit();


    //ibInsertarJugada = insertarJugadaFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.ibInsertarJugada);
    ibInsertarJugada = findViewById(R.id.ibInsertarJugada);
    ibInsertarJugada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(EstadisticasActivity.this, "Has hecho click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

¿Cómo puedo gestionar dicho evento?, ¿es posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu fragment puedes crear una variable de tipo `View.OnClickListener` y en el `onCreateView` pasar esa variable como parámetro del `setOnClickListener` del botón, así:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public View.OnClickListener listener;


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        Button boton = v.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        boton.setOnClickListener(listener);

        return v;
    }
```

En la Activity se crea la instancia del fragment y luego se crea una instancia del `View.OnClickListener` y se le asigna a la variable que se declaró en el fragment:

```
 //instancia del fragment
   BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();


//inicializar la variable listener con una instancia de OnClickListener
fragment.listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "boton presionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
```

Comment: Estimado crrlos, ¡mil gracias!, línea por línea. Lo que necesitaba era recuperar el valor almacenado en un EditText por lo que he seguido el mismo procedimiento que con el Buttón y recuperado su valor al ser éste pulsado. Gracias, muchas gracias.